# How to read and write id3v1 and id3v2 tags in Elixir

Tags: erlang, mp4, elixir, id3

I would like to scan music files and read/write metadata using Elixir (this whole project is about learning Elixir - so please don't tell me to use Python!). As I understand it, I have two choices: call a system utility or (as no libraries exist in Erlang or Elixir that I am aware of) write an Elixir library. For m4a files, I make a system call to MP4Box and it writes an xml file to disk. I then read in the file, parse it, and load the data into a database.

```
def parse(file_name) do
  System.cmd("MP4Box", ["-diso",file_name])
  Ainur.XmlParser.parse(xml_file_name(file_name))
  |> get_tags
end
```

Very slow, especially for thousands of files. And I want it to run at start up everytime to check for changed/new files.

Now I am trying to do the same for mp3's with id3 tags. I tried libid3-tools on Ubuntu and it only found the id3v1 tags. eyeD3 only found id3v2 tags. My mp3's have both so I need to make sure there are the same (I suppose I could delete the id3v1 tags, but I have been led to believe that id3v1 tags are needed on legacy equipment).

Are there any Erlang or Elixir libraries for music metadata? If not, are system calls to ubuntu utilities my best choice (any recommendations on which ones)?

Or do I need to write a library to obtain reasonable performance? If so, is there an existing library in a functional language that I could try to port?

Or is it possible to call a library written in another language directly from Elixir (without the system call)?

Comment: ,possible this links you will help: http://benjamintan.io/blog/2014/06/10/elixir-bit-syntax-and-id3/                          http://www.citizen428.net/blog/2010/09/04/erlang-bit-syntax-and-id3

Comment: Yes, those links are great because they show how powerful Elixir bit syntax is. No need for an external library.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used the above link as a model to read id3v1 tags and it was quite straightforward. I hesitate to attack id3v2 or mp4 tags because they are more complex. I think Elixir is a joy to use and would work well for that, but I have limited knowledge of these formats (I fear the ever-expanding side project). I think I will first look at the Elixir NIF/Ports mentioned by Paweł below. Any idea where to find more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use erlang NIFs (http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) to wrap an external library

Answer (score 1):

In this project we have a module written in Elixir which extracts ID3 tags from mp3:

https://github.com/anisiomarxjr/shoutcast_server/blob/master/lib/mp3_file.ex

To use:

```
id3 = Mp3File.extract_id3("./test/fixtures/nederland.mp3")
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wrote a module for reading id3v1 tags, but it is nice to compare. Now I am looking at id3v2 - much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented ID3v2 tag reading (not writing) in Elixir. It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/Cheezmeister/elixir-id3v2) and [Hex](https://hex.pm/packages/id3v2).

Support is *very* basic; I implemented the bare minimum to support my use case. There's lots of bugs, but all the building blocks are there to fork/improve/contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try directly reading the binary of the file to find the tag in question.

Check the [File.stream/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stream!/3) docs to get started.